# why is this not printing out a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm trying to get this to print out a value in a dictionary from a key that the user inputs, but nothing is coming out. any ideas?

```
u_items=input("Enter 'list' to see a list of items, or 'Book', 'Apple', 'Toy', 'Pumpkin', 'Bowl' or 'Purse' to see the item's price: ")
u_items=u_items.title()

inventory={'Book':'18', 'Apple':'3', 'Toy':'7', 'Pumpkin':'9', 'Bowl':'5', 'Purse':'30'}

if u_items in inventory[u_items] == True:
    print("A " + u_items + "costs $" + inventory[u_items])

elif u_items == 'List':
    print(items(inventory))
```

Comment: @Keikoku - A string method that makes the string like a title of a book.  To see for yourself, run this in the interpreter: `'happy birthday'.title()`.  Or, here are the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.title).

Comment: @iCodez Oh, that's pretty cool..I suppose. Doesn't look like a very smart converter but I guess it does its job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement is constructed wrong.  It should be like this:

```
if u_items in inventory:
```

This tests if `u_items` (the key the user entered) exists in the dictionary.

What you were doing before was seeing if `u_items` existed in the value returned by indexing `inventory` with `u_items`.  So, if the user entered `'apple'`, your code would be interpreted like this:

```
if 'Apple' in '3' == True:
```

Comment: and the items[inventory] isn't working. guessing my syntax is wrong?

Comment: @rs19 - Ah, yes.  I missed that.  `item` is a method of `dict`, so you should do this: `inventory.items()`